# How to make the part of the line I need?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I need to extract from the table column only part of a row - which can be from 0 to 4 characters long:

> "address":"124"

I know that this can be done as an 'extract'/findall functions. but it turns out only to set a mask on which only parts of the line that will fall under this mask will fight off. and as I said, the code length is different, so this method is not effective.
Please tell me how to correctly set the mask for the selection.

Sample row from table column:

> {'latitude': '37.80505999961946', 'human_address':
>   '{"address":"0","city":"Oakland","state":"Ca","zip":""}',
>   'needs_recoding': False, 'longitude': '-122.27301999967312'}

```
df['latitude_1'] = df['Location 1'].str.extract('(\"\d\d\d\d)', expand=True)
```

Comment: I think there's unnecessary information in this question making it confusing. Are you asking how to use regex to extract 1-4 digits from a string (or essentially the house number part of an address from the rest of it) using [pandas string handling api](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.3/api.html#string-handling)?

Comment: Yes, I ask about - how to extract a house number in a new column?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```
dic = {'latitude': '37.80505999961946', 'human_address': '{"address":"1234","city":"Oakland","state":"Ca","zip":""}', 'needs_recoding': False, 'longitude': '-122.27301999967312'}, {'latitude': '37.80505999961946', 'human_address': '{"address":"0","city":"Oakland","state":"Ca","zip":""}', 'needs_recoding': False, 'longitude': '-122.27301999967312'}
df = pd.DataFrame(list(dic))
df


          human_address                                   latitude             longitude        needs_recoding
0   {"address":"1234","city":"Oakland","state":"Ca...   37.80505999961946   -122.27301999967312 False
1   {"address":"0","city":"Oakland","state":"Ca","...   37.80505999961946   -122.27301999967312 False


import re
df.human_address.apply(lambda s: re.search('\"address\"*:*\"\d{0,4}\"', s).group())


0    "address":"1234"
1       "address":"0"
Name: human_address, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user pandas str.extract indeed, You just need to tweak your regex pattern.

Below is the Dataframe taken from @Ananay Mital..

```
>>> df
                                       human_address           latitude            longitude  needs_recoding
0  {"address":"1234","city":"Oakland","state":"Ca...  37.80505999961946  -122.27301999967312           False
1  {"address":"0","city":"Oakland","state":"Ca","...  37.80505999961946  -122.27301999967312           False
```

This is how you can use str.extract to get your results:

```
>>> df.human_address.str.extract('(\"address\":\"\d{0,4}\")')
                  0
0  "address":"1234"
1     "address":"0"
```

OR, as below ..

```
>>> df.human_address.str.extract(r'("address":"\d{0,4}")')
                  0
0  "address":"1234"
1     "address":"0"
```